# Proving that Lindelof Is a Topological Property

Tags: general-topology

We have that a topological property of a topological space X is a property that is satisfied by every topological space Y which is homeomorphic to X. So to show that Lindelof is a topological property, we need to show that if X is Lindelof then so is Y. So assuming X is Lindelof, we have that every open cover of X has a countable subcover of Y. How do we use this to prove that Y is also Lindelof?

Comment: Note that every homeomorphism is open and continuous, so open sets are preserved by it, both ways.